# Calling contract method leads to Metamask chrome extension error (DOM Exception)

Tags: javascript, web3js, metamask

I have a contract that looks something like this:

```
contract Lottery {
// public we will write a front end application that will easily access public
address public manager;
address payable[] public players;

constructor() public {
    // msg global variable when we send a tx or when we do a function call
    manager = msg.sender;
}

function enter() public payable {
    // used for validation, evaluates to true continue, evaluates to false means return immediatelty
    require(msg.value > .01 ether);
    players.push(msg.sender);
}
```

I deploy this on Rinkeby successfully, and I am using the metamask web3 provider. `lottery` is my contract object. I want to make a simple call for the manager variable in a react component as such:

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { manager: '' };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    // with metamask there is a default address (the first one on the array) so no need to call with from address
    try {
      const manager = await lottery.methods.manager().call();

      this.setState({ manager });
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
```

However, I end up getting an error with the Metamask extension that is absolutely undecipherable:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Which web3 version are you using? Apparently it does not work in beta.41. consider installing beta.37.

```
npm install --save web3@1.0.0-beta.37
```

Reference: https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/6080